# What kernel flags and PCIe setting needed for bus mastering

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, dma

I am having trouble getting bus-mastering DMA working on a device driver in Ubuntu with kernel `5.3.0-68-generic`.

- I have enabled bus mastering with `pci_set_master` (when using `lspci -v`, the PCIe device will have the bus_master flag) and I am allocating a DMA buffer with `dma_alloc_coherent`.
- I take the `dma_addr_t` returned by the dma alloc and pass that to the device and then I use the kernel virtual address with a chrdev mmap driver to map the address into userspace (using `remap_pfn_range`) where a userspace driver can populate the DMA memory region.

It doesn't appear that the the PCIe device can see the memory updates in the DMA region, is there perhaps some dma, iommu, or pci settings I need to enable to allow the PCIe device to read back into system memory as the bus master?

Comment: You should understand the hardware architecture. Usually PCIe devices have **private** DMA bus mastering which has nothing to do with GPDMA.

Comment: You should probably be using `dma_mmap_coherent` to mmap the DMA buffer instead of `remap_pfn_range`, but I don't think that is why it is not working. Both the CPU and the device are able to access the buffer contents, but you obviously need to control the device in some way to make it read or write the buffer.